# How to setup a service continualy fetching data from Server, even when phone is sleeping?

Tags: java, android, service

**My goal is to have a service polling a Server from the background and notifying the user he gets interesting data. Basically just like WhatsApp does (WhatsApp can be closed and the phone can be sleeping and you are still notified whenever you get a message).**

I know about the Service class as well as the IntentService class and that they can  do background operations and extend above the lifecycle of an activity.
To make myself familiar with them I wrote a test project with a server which basically just accepts socket connections and prints its input into the console.

**Client-side, though, I just cannot get the service to stick around. After 5 seconds of the app being closed the service stops (onDestroy is not even called).**

I've tried returning `START_STICKY` in the `onStartCommand()` method. I've also tried different approaches polling the data, such as using google's Volley library to fire requests every 5 seconds, as well as an ongoing, lasting Socket connection sending packets of data to the Server every 5 seconds. None of those attempts have been working, though, and the service always is killed. The sticky mode will . I've read some things about AlarmManager to restart the killed process, but some people said that this approach would be bad practice since the AlarmManager can be quite unreliable.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Here is my client-side code:
This is the service's `onStartCommand`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service has started");

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("chId", "chName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                channel.enableLights(true);
                channel.enableVibration(true);

                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            showNotification("Service has started");

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long now;

            BufferedReader input = null;
            PrintWriter output = null;

            try {
                Socket connection = new Socket("192.168.178.21", 6789);

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                output = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (true) {
                now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if ((now - start) >= 5000) {
                    output.write("Hi" + System.lineSeparator());
                    output.flush();
                    start = now;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and its `onDestroy` method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    showNotification("on Destroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The `showNotification` method just pushes a new notifcation forward:

```
private void showNotification(String text) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "chId")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setTicker("Ticker")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("Titel")
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
            .setContentText(text);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification.build());
}
```

I have been reading about this topic a lot so I hope this is not a duplicate question. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: [Background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all)

Comment: "My goal is to have a service polling a Server from the background and notifying the user he gets interesting data. Basically just like WhatsApp does" -- most likely WhatsApp is using Firebase Cloud Messaging, not polling. "After 5 seconds of the app being closed the service stops" -- what exactly do you mean by "the app being closed"? "as well as an ongoing, lasting Socket connection sending packets of data to the Server every 5 seconds" -- that is what you appear to be trying to do here, and the busy loop is unlikely to be helping your case.

Comment: Thank you, @prashant17. I believe JobScheduler is better suited for me.

Comment: Hey, @CommonsWare, you were actually right about FCM. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!